# How do i redirect to controller when a button is clicked inside of popup window in mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

How do i redirect to controller when a button is clicked inside of popup window. I will explain my issue clearly .I have one form called **VisitorsForm**. In that i have one dropdown called **Purpose of visit**. If I select purpose of visit as "**Trail** "it open one pop-up window .After enter all the values which is inside of pop-up window and click the save button means it does not redirect to controller.

**My VisitorsForm Screen**

[image: Pop-window]

In the above image i have field called purpose of visit.if i select purpose of visit as **Trial**. It open the pop-up window. In pop-up window I entered all the values and click the save button means it didn't redirect to controller.

**My Model**(**VisitorsViewModel**)

```
 public Nullable<System.Guid> POVisitID { get; set; } 
 public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerTrialItemID { get; set; }
 public System.Guid ItemID{ get; set; }
 public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult CreateCustomertrialForm(VisitorsViewModel visitorsformviewmodel)
{
    var itemslist = Session["itemList"] as List<VisitorsViewModel>;
    var customertrialformid = Guid.NewGuid(); 
    var trialdateobj = DateTime.Now.Date;
    var customertrialform = new CustomerTrialForm();

    customertrialform.CustomerTrialFormID = customertrialformid;
    customertrialform.TrialDate = trialdateobj;
    customertrialform.Ends = visitorsformviewmodel.Ends;
    customertrialform.CustomerTrialItemID = visitorsformviewmodel.CustomerTrialItemID;

    var multipleitemlist = new List<CustomerTrialItem>();
    foreach (var item in itemslist)
    { 
        var customertrialitem = new CustomerTrialItem();
        customertrialitem.CustomerTrialItemID = Guid.NewGuid();
        customertrialitem.ItemID = item.ItemID;
        customertrialitem.Quantity = item.Quantity;
        db.CustomerTrialItems.Add(customertrialitem);
    }

    db.CustomerTrialForms.Add(customertrialform);
    db.SaveChanges();
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View();
}
```

**My View**

```
 @model CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.VisitorsViewModel
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
 <fieldset>
 @Html.Label("Purpose of Visit", new { @class = "control-label", styles = "font-family: Arial;" })
 @Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })
 </div>
 </div>

//pop-up window code inside of parent page

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCustomertrialForm", "VisitorsForm", new { Areas ="Sales"}))
{
<div id="Trial-dialog-modal" title="Trial Form" style="display:none">
<div class="box-body">
<div>Customer Name</div>
<div id="customername"></div>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerID, new { id = "customerid" })

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SampleNo)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SampleNo, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SortName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SortName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })


 //pop-up window Save button

  <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" CreateCustomertrialForm", "VisitorsForm")'" />

}

//Second methid i used to save pop up window
//Pop up window Save button

<input id="Button1" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveCustomertrialform()" />

  <script>
          function SaveCustomertrialform() {
            debugger;
            var url = '@Url.Action("SaveCustomertrialForm", "VisitorsForm", new { Area = "Sales" })';
            var CustomerID = $("#customerid").val();
            var SampleNo = $("#SampleNo").val();
            var SortName = $("#SortName").val();
            var YarnCount = $("#YarnCount").val();

      var CustomerTrialForm = {
                "SampleNo": '' + SampleNo + '', "SortName": '' + SortName + '',
                "YarnCount": '' + YarnCount + '', "Ends": '' + Ends + ''

   };
            $.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
            $.post(url, CustomerTrialForm, function (data) {

 alert("Success")
                $("#dialog-modal").dialog("close");
            });
        }
    </script>

 //Parent Page Save Button

<button id="SaverBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-left" value='EnterKey'>Save<i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>

</fieldSet>
}
```

I tried many ways to clear the issue.But I can't clear my issue. Any one help to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You have nested forms which is invalid html and not supported (and will you please stop dumping all your code in your questions - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). You also have a button in the inner form which is just making a GET and not sending any data you your `CreateCustomertrialForm()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke i will remove some of dump codes .Sry for that now my doubt is if i change that to httpget means it will work . And also have to remove that (using (Html.begin form) which i wrote second time

Comment: Yes, but if you perform a GET, then you shouldn't be sending any information with it. If you're trying to save, you should be doing a POST.

Comment: Your 'Save' button in the popup needs to be a submit button and submit to a `[HttpPost]` method. But are you wanting to save just the controls in the pop-up or all the controls in the form? (the other data would be lost if you just submit the popup)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually i am saving the values which is entered inside of pop-up window

Comment: @StephenMuecke the parent page is visitors form .That is Get action method. In parent page i have one field called purpose of visit . if i select purpose of visit it will open this pop-up window.

Comment: Then what is the point of the other form controls since everything the user has entered will be lost as soon as you submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke Before i used one method that is  i get all the pop-up window  values in jquery and then pass that values to controller now also i can use that method to save this pop-up window values.But i have one issue in that method

Comment: @StephenMuecke see my updated code which i wrote in view. In that i used second method as jquery to pass the values to controller. But the problem is i have one multiple item adding option in the popup window,. That is ItemID and Quantity have to add multiple item in the list. hich is shown in that image . So i didnt know how to get that multiple item in this jquery . Can you give me solution for this problem

Comment: Its not clear at all why you doing any of this. It seems that your popup just contains additional information that you need to be entered based on the selected option. Why are you not saving all the data in one action (and the inputs in the 'popup' would just be inside a hidden `<div>` that is displayed is the option is selected). When you submit, all the data associated with you model is posted in one action to one controller method

Comment: @StephenMuecke if i post my parent page action codes and popup windows codes means it will look like many dump codes there .Now u asking me why you save both parent page code and poup window codein same action. Please tell me how to do that . Can you give eg code . Do you want my parent page code means i will post here. But i am sure i wont post all code

Comment: Just have one form and include the controls that are currently in you 'popup' inside a `<div>` that is styled as hidden (not inside another form). Use javascript to display the that `<div>` if the option is selected so the user can fill them out.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that means u asking me to create like partial view??

Comment: It does not need to be a partial (but it could be if you want)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please can you give some example code. So that i can understand easily.I understood what you saying but need some clarification . can you help me with this

Comment: @StephenMuecke i will follow your comments but you tell your answer when you get time